# How to use aws cli --generate-cli-skeleton

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I have seen the option `--generate-cli-skeleton` in a lot of aws CLI docs, however every time I add it to a aws cmd I get `Unknown options: --generate-cli-skeleton`.

Can someone tell me or point me to instructions on how to use this option

thanks
Art

Comment: can you give an example of the command you are trying to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was added in version 1.5.5 (https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#155), make sure your are using version 1.5.5 or higher.  You can get the version via `aws --version`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out what you would think would be AWS default behavior, that is, install the latest cli by default. Thanks